# Closing an Akka Stream for resource cleanup

Tags: akka, apache-kafka, akka-stream

When using Akka Streams, is there any way to close/shutdown a stream that is not required anymore for resource cleanup?

**EDIT**: When the source is made up of an infinite stream, it may never be completed and I would like to stop it before the completed source.

Example usage:

```
Source.from(publisher)
      .map((p) -> p)
      .to(Sink.ignore())
      .run(materializer)
```

Is there a way to shutdown the stream?

Comment: The stream should stop naturally when the upstream Source no longer has any data to satisfy the downstream demand.  So when the Publisher signals completion downstream this materialized flow instance should stop.  Or, if you have a long running flow you could consider using a separate materializer just for it and then call `shutdown()` on the materializer

Comment: Since the Source is a publisher and it can be an infinite stream (in my case it is a stream from Kafka), it will never be completed.

Comment: Via the `Publisher`, can you get access to the `Subscription` from the downstream `Flow` so that you can cancel it?  What is the impl class for your `Publisher`?

Comment: I only have the `Publisher` interface.  I am using the `reactive-kafka` from https://github.com/softwaremill/reactive-kafka and the difficulty encountered is when trying to consume a stream of kafka events and then I would like to somehow unsubscribe from that stream.

Comment: The latest release of reactive-kafka (0.8.1) provided support to close the source publisher using the method `cancel()` and solves this problem for this specific library.  I'm still interested to find ways how this can be done generically for all akka streams though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could run the `Stream` on an independent `ActorMaterializer` and call shutdown on the ActorMaterializer after a certain period of time:

```
val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

val temporaryStream = {

  val localMat = ActorMaterializer()(actorSystem)

  import actorSystem.dispatcher
  actorSystem.scheduler.scheduleOnce(10 minutes) { localMat.shutdown() }

  Source.from(publisher)
        .map((p) -> p)
        .to(Sink.ignore())
        .run()(localMat)
}
```

Similarly you could return the ActorMaterializer instead of the materialized stream and shutdown the ActorMaterializer based on some external condition other than time.

Comment: I find crating a new actor system for every stream rather inefficient.  In my scenario, I am using akka streams to subscribe with Apache Kafka topics, and this requires multiple streams and would take a lot of resources (a thread pool for each topic) if I use your suggestion.

Comment: I was using the `Materializer` interface instead of the `ActorMaterializer` and did not find shutdown method on the interface.  Thanks!